# how to change text color of a particular item in navigation view?

Tags: android, android-studio, textcolor, navigationview

I tried alomst every link on stackoverflow but I could not find the right solution to my question. I tried this...

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:itemTextColor="#fff"
    app:itemIconTint="#fff"
    android:background="#393737"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_navigation"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_navigation_drawer"/>
```

But its changing the text color of each item. Is there any to change text color of single item? I am talking about changing the text color of particular item i.e. if we have four items

- sugar
- bread
- milk
- egg

This list is embedded in menu of navigation view. If we want to change the color of milk to red. How to do that??

Comment: can u please elaborate ....how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do that programatically.

```
// Get the navigation view first. 
mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
```

Now you need to get the menu item from the navigation view and set the icon here.

```
// Get the index of milk
mNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(INDEX_OF_MILK).setIcon(R.drawable.milk_red);
```

The idea is keeping two separate icons for milk. You may change the icon anytime when needed. So the complete pseudo code should look like

```
if(milkIsRed)
    mNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(INDEX_OF_MILK).setIcon(R.drawable.milk_red);
else 
    mNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(INDEX_OF_MILK).setIcon(R.drawable.milk_white);
```

Comment: Original question was about colored text, not colored icon.

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize your navigation drawer View for that you can use this link  http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

XML look Like

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/nav_home" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_photos"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_photo_library_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/nav_photos" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_movies"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_local_movies_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/nav_movies" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_notifications"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/nav_notifications" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/nav_settings" />
</group>
```